# ¿Cómo recibir las nofificaciones IPN de mercado pago?

Tags: php, mercadopago

Estoy intentando recibir las notificaciones IPN de mercado pago, pero no las recibo, para empezar estoy intentando enviarme un email (tengo perfectamente configurado mi localhost para poder hacerlo) al notificar que el pago se realizo con éxito.

Estoy usando usuarios de prueba que, según la documentación, es perfectamente factible usarlos y enviar notificaciones ipn.

Entiendo que este tipo de notificaciones se comunican con mi página php y ejecutan el script estando yo fuera de línea, quizás me confundo...

Usé el ejemplo que tiene mercado pago en su documentación, en mi página `notificacion.php` integre el ejemplo:

```
<?php
require_once "mercadopago.php";

$mp = new MP("usuario de prueba id", "usuario de prueba SECRET");

if (!isset($_GET["id"], $_GET["topic"]) || !ctype_digit($_GET["id"])) {
http_response_code(400);
return;
}

// Get the payment and the corresponding merchant_order reported by the IPN.
if($_GET["topic"] == 'payment'){
$payment_info = $mp->get("/collections/notifications/" . $_GET["id"]);
$merchant_order_info = $mp->get("/merchant_orders/" .             $payment_info["response"]["collection"]["merchant_order_id"]);
// Get the merchant_order reported by the IPN.
} else if($_GET["topic"] == 'merchant_order'){
$merchant_order_info = $mp->get("/merchant_orders/" . $_GET["id"]);
}

if ($merchant_order_info["status"] == 200) {
// If the payment's transaction amount is equal (or bigger) than the     merchant_order's amount you can release your items 
$paid_amount = 0;
//AQUI ENVIO EL MAIL !!!
mail("mcd77.1990@gmail.com", "prueba notificacion", "hola mundo");

foreach ($merchant_order_info["response"]["payments"] as  $payment) {
    if ($payment['status'] == 'approved'){
        $paid_amount += $payment['transaction_amount'];
    }   
}

if($paid_amount >= $merchant_order_info["response"]["total_amount"]){
    if(count($merchant_order_info["response"]["shipments"]) > 0) { // The     merchant_order has shipments
        if($merchant_order_info["response"]["shipments"][0]["status"] ==     "ready_to_ship"){
            print_r("Totally paid. Print the label and release your item.");
        }
    } else { // The merchant_order don't has any shipments
        print_r("Totally paid. Release your item.");
    }
} else {
    print_r("Not paid yet. Do not release your item.");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: En principio podrías saber si efectivamente te están llegando las notificaciones mirando en el `access_log` de tu webserver, buscando si hay pedidos al `notificaciones.php` (que no sean tuyos). Con esto podrías saber al menos si el problema está en tu código o si directamente no llegan las notificaciones.

Comment: hice algunas modificaciones al código ,  este nuevo  anda bien, si le paso cobros ya realizados es decir, notificaciones.php?topic=payment&id="cualquier id de un cobro realizado" desde el navegador, hace lo que le pido, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema al realizar un cobro con mensajes de prueba sin yo intervenir directamente en el proceso, voy a probar tu recomendación igualmente :)

Comment: Estuve revisando el access.log de xamp, y no me llegan directamente

Comment: ¿La URL para la notificación es accesible desde internet? Por ejemplo si pruebas acceder a la URL desde un host fuera de tu red local, ¿ahí aparece en el `acces_log`?